# The concept of first child under parent setting margin based on first child rendered in the browser

Tags: html, css, margin

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Above is a sample code that I have emulated on the codepen [here](https://codepen.io/codeispoetry/pen/xdymZJ).

The child element one and two can be floated either right or left and vice versa; That means If one is floated right the other can be floated left and vice versa.

Now my question is →

The first child is based on the order in which it is written in HTML? If that is true than that means irrespective of whether it is rendered in browser first when floated right or second when floated left it will always remain the first child or the first or Nth child is not based on the order in which it is written in HTML, but on the order it is rendered in browser.

WHY AM I ASKING SUCH QUESTIONS.

there are moments especially in wordpress when the only difference between the two templates is that in one the sidebar is ion left and in another the sidebar is in right. LESS IS MORE there is no reason to create a separate template because the entire HTML is same but only difference is the order of 2 columns.

so I was thinking a situation where we can use some first child property if we can set `margin-right` on the column, which is the one that appears first in the browser.

If this is the case →
https://codepen.io/codeispoetry/pen/xdymZJ

then `margin-right` should apply on `.one` however if we reverse the order that is green appears first and then blue then `margin-right` should apply on `.two`

I wish to do this not through javascript or php, but CSS may be exploiting `first child` property in some way.

Comment: It is how they are positioned in the markup. [Codepen 1](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmzaaP) ... [Codepen 2](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNmwwq) ... This means you can't do what you think, it will always set the `margin-right` the first child in the markup, even if it appears to be the second visually

Comment: Let's suppose there was an `:nth-displayed-child` pseudo element. What would happen if you wrote `:nth-displayed-child(1) { float: right; }` and  `:nth-displayed-child(2) { float: left; }` ?

Comment: correct @LGson, but in your version the Layout is breaking → https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNmwwq?editors=1100 it is leaving space towards it right and in real world website that will look ugly. In short we want that margin-right should be applicable on the item that is appearing firrst or floating right.

Comment: @AdiYogi that would be for you to control via your design and what you're expecting of the page. See my answer - CSS can't react to the layout in this way, instead is is part of the process which is defining the layout in the first place. It's not a two-way process.

Comment: But as I showed in your recent question, this will be able to do with flexbox

Comment: There are some challenges in that to so was thinking if this could be done. space-between has some challenges too.

Comment: Well, if you let us in on what issue you have with flexbox and space-between, we most likely can sort that out.

Comment: I have created one more layout → https://codepen.io/codeispoetry/pen/MmPmpx space-between is causing some issues. so was thinking something else that i posted as a question here.

Comment: That sample is a whole new question, so end this one and post a new where you explain how `space-between` doesn't do what you want and you get help with that

Comment: Ok sir, but do we have the solution for what I posted as a question here?

Comment: Yes, you have...by @ADyson, which pretty much says, _Nope, can't be done without script_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done entirely on where the elements appear in the markup.

See this updated version of your first example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVJdBX . The element identified as "first-child" has a red border.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="one child"></div>
    <div class="two child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  height: 900px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.one {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 900px;
  float: right;
  width: 33%;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.two {
  background-color: green;
  width:60%;
  height: 900px;
  float: left;
}

.child:first-child
{
  border:solid 1px red;
}
```

I don't think what you're suggesting can work. CSS *tells* the browser how/where to render things on screen, it cannot *react* to where things are rendered, in order to apply more rules, which is effectively what you're hoping for.

Comment: Ok Buddy. Can we think of some hack?

Comment: this is possible through javascript, but I do not want to polify the website with unnecessary scripting.

Comment: @AdiYogi Since CSS isn't clever enough to make a decision based on what you want, script is necessary.

Comment: ok sir. should I accept the solution or should I delete the question?

Comment: @AdiYogi - You should accept the *answer* - which is "No, you can't do that in CSS",

Comment: @AdiYogi Yes...you just got one here :)

Comment: Thanks, This helps newcomers like me.